# obtain not disabled input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several input text element,

I have button `disable some input` for disable some input element(s),

I have also button `see values`, for see all input values,

What I need: 
for example I click on button `disable some input`, now some inputs are disabled right?

and now if click on button `see values`, I want see only that input values, which are not disabled.

I make almost all, but I dont know, how make this condition: `if element already is disabled`

please see demo
http://jsfiddle.net/WW8UF/4/

The body is:

```
<form>
      <ul id="my_ul">
             <li><input type="text" value="a" /></li>
             <li><input type="text"  value="s" /></li>
             <li><input type="text" value="d" /></li>
       </ul>
</form>

<div id="disable_btn">disable some input</div>
<div id="see_values">see values</div>
```

The js, using jQuery 1.8.2

```
$(document).ready( function () {  

        $("#disable_btn").on("click", function () {
            $("#my_ul li:eq(0) input").prop("disabled", true);
        });


        $("#see_values").on("click", function () {
            $("#my_ul li").each ( function () {
                if (1==1/*if this input is not disabled*/) {
                    alert ( $(this).find("input").val()  );
                }
            });
        });
});
```

​

Comment: See working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WW8UF/6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to loop over every `li`, just get the inputs which are not disabled:

```
$("#my_ul li input:not([disabled])").each ( function () { ... });
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/WW8UF/10/

You could also use

```
$("#my_ul li input:enabled").each ( function () { ... });
```

Which is a bit cleaner. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/WW8UF/11/

Answer (score 1):

The condition is:

```
!$(this).find('input').attr('disabled')
```

Comment: For cross browsing, .prop() is advised for disabled/checked

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another try:

```
$("#see_values").on("cick", function () {
        $("#my_ul li input").not(":disabled").each ( function ()
                alert ( $(this).val());

        });

    });
```

JQuery provides the pseudo-selector ":disabled", so you just ignore those.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It also provides the psuedo-selector :enabled, negating the need for a NOT.  (See what I did there?)

Answer (score 0):

Use a better selector.

Change:-

```
$("#my_ul li").each ( function () {
  if (1==1/*if this input is not disabled*/) {
    alert ( $(this).find("input").val()  );
  }          
});
```

to:-

```
// Perform search with selector
$("#my_ul li input:enabled").each ( function () {
  // No if statement required
  alert ( $(this).find("input").val()  );          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An other possibility:

```
$(document).ready( function () {  

        $("#disable_btn").on("click", function () {
            $("#my_ul li:eq(0) input").prop("disabled", true);
        });


        $("#see_values").on("click", function () {
            $("#my_ul li input").each ( function () {
                if (!$(this).is(':disabled')) { //or if ($(this).is(':enabled'))
                    alert ( $(this).val()  );
                }

            });

        });

});
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WW8UF/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Just check your *disabled* property value, in the same way that you have assigned it, like this:

```
if (!$(this).find("input").prop("disabled")) {
     // do something to this
}
```